# Show that a symmetric random walk with hit any number with probability 1

Tags: probability, martingales, random-walk

I'm supposed to show this with martingale convergence thm. I have tried setting up one barrier at a fixed $n$. And the martingale convergence says it will converges to a random variable almost surely. But why would that imply it will hit the barrier?

EDIT: I think I just came up with a way to show this as I'm typing (setting up another barrier and gradually moving it to infinity). But I'd still like to know possible, more straightforward alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $M_n$ to be the location after $n$ steps, and $T$ to be the first time at which our random walk is equal to 1. Then, $X_n = M_{\min(T,n)}$ forms a Martingale, and since the $X_n$ are bounded above by 1 by Martingale convergence will converge a.s. to some random variable $X$.

We want to show that $X=1$. Off the top of my head I can't think of any elegant way to do this, but we can observe that since $X,X_n$ are integer valued the PDFs of $X_n$ converge pointwise to the PDF of $X$. One can then check that this forces $X=1$. (since $P(X_{n+1}=1) = P(X_n=1) + \frac{1}{2}P(X_{n}=0)$ and $|P(X_{n+1}=1)- P(X_n=1)| \to 0$, this forces $P(X_n=0)\to 0$, and one can argue onwards to show that $P(X_n= k)=0$ for any negative $k$.)

This tells us that our original random walk $M_n$ hits 1 almost surely, which implies that we hit any integer point almost surely.